# Combine startsWith and all in odata query

Tags: c#, rest, odata

I'm working on a project which requires me to query some data from an Odata enabled API.

The data looks like this (simplified):

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Parent> parents {get; set;}
}

public class Parent
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The data I need to query is: "Any student of which the parent's name starts with 'x'".

I've already tried several things like:
`$filter=startswith(student/parent/all(parent : parent/name, 'X')`

But I cannot seem to get it working.
Surely I'm missing something, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Any pointers on this?

Comment: GET student?$filter=parent/name/any(s:startswith(s, 'X'))

Comment: Thanks! I was pulling my hair out with this one!

Comment: Does the query from the comment work?